# How do I show dynamic and dependable list of values of model field on Front End using Django Forms?

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, dynamic-list

I have a `Detail` Model which has a `ForeignKey()` of `User` Model. I want to show the list of `subject` (which is a field of `Detail` Model) associated with a single user, at the Front End in Template. It should be a dropdown menu and user should be able to select the subject from the list and submit the form.

How should I accomplish it?

Below is my models.py

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField()
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField()
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField()
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField()
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject, (self.user.username)} Details'
```

and below is my views.py:

```
def performanceCalculator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm(request.POST, user=request.user)

        if performance_form.is_valid():
            sub = performance_form.cleaned_data['subject']

            detail = Detail.objects.all().filter(user=request.user, subject=sub).first()

            result = fuzz_algo(detail.skype_session_attendance,
                detail.internal_course_marks, detail.programming_lab_activity,
                detail.mid_term_marks, detail.final_term_marks)

            messages.success(request, result)

            return redirect('performance_calculator')
    else:
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'performance_form': performance_form,        
    }

    return render(request, 'users/performance_calculator.html', context)
```

and below is forms.py:

```
class PerformanceCalculatorForm(forms.Form):
    subject = # what should I put here in order to make a dropdown list?

    class Meta:
        fields = ['subject']
```

Below is the updated code of PerformanceCalculatorForm in views.py:

```
class PerformanceCalculatorForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(PerformanceCalculatorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['subject'].queryset = Detail.objects.filter(user=user)

    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['subject']
```

Comment: 10 views but no help? :(

Comment: @Paaksing can you help me in it?

Comment: Hi, back here, you want a drop down selection menu right ? I think the docs have specified that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices have a look at it while I read more of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put it here

```
class PerformanceCalculatorForm(forms.Form):
    subject = # what should I put here in order to make a dropdown list?

    class Meta:
        fields = ['subject']
```

There are snippets on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices

Instead, do it on your models.py

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    #create your choice tuple
    SUBJECT_CHOICES = [
        #(actual value on database, human readable text)
        ('math','Math'),
        ('algebra1', 'Algebra I'),
        ('calculus3','Calculus III'),
    ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                                              #here add the choices
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField()
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField()
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField()
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField()
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject, (self.user.username)} Details'
```

By passing a tuple to the choices a values, it will be replaced on the render with a select box.

---

**UPDATE related to adding choices dinamically to Model field:**
A better and practical way would be having a function that returns each subjects and append it to your choices list.

In your models.py leave it like before.

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField()
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField()
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField()
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField()
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject, (self.user.username)} Details'
```

For the issue that you commented, you can just return the `__str__` to whatever to you like but separate it using a special character, then this will be seen on the POST request and using `split()` to get your `subject` out of the queryset object.

At the `__str__` of your model:

```
    return f'{self.user.username}-{self.subject}'
```

now in your views.py use `split()` to the the part that you want to match

```
def performanceCalculator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm(request.POST, user=request.user)

        if performance_form.is_valid():
            sub = performance_form.cleaned_data['subject']
            sub = str(sub).split('-')[1] #user-subject will get the subject part

            detail = Detail.objects.all().filter(user=request.user, subject=sub).first()

            result = fuzz_algo(detail.skype_session_attendance,
                detail.internal_course_marks, detail.programming_lab_activity,
                detail.mid_term_marks, detail.final_term_marks)

            messages.success(request, result)

            return redirect('performance_calculator')
    else:
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'performance_form': performance_form,        
    }

    return render(request, 'users/performance_calculator.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi @Paaksing
Actually, I did not want to manually pass the subject names. I wanted to pass the subjects names of the current logged in user. By the way I got the solution, but now I have another issue.

Comment: I used `__init__()` constructor in `PerformanceCalculatorForm()` to get the subjects of the crrently logged in user. But the new issue I have is that, for this to work, I had to change the `__str__` method of `Detail` Model to return only the subject name, and because of this if more than one user have same subjects then in the Details Table in Admin Panel, I see the same name of subjects multiple times, and can't differentiate which subject belongs to which user, unless I dont open them and see the username. Any solution for this?

Comment: I had to change `return f'{self.subject, (self.user.username)} Details'` to `return f'{self.subject}'` in order for it to only return the subject name because if I return it with the user name, the `detail` variable in `performanceCalculator()` view will get `None` because the returned value (subject name with username) by `__str__` method will not match with any of the subject name of currently logged in user. But solving this issue, now I have the subject names without username in the Admin Panel and unable to differentiate which subject belongs to which user.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar That is not practical, but you can use a trick, just `return f'{self.user.username}-{self.subject}'` and then when you want to access it, just call the `split('-')[1]` after your str variable. and it will get the second split after your "-" character.

Comment: Can you give the example by editing code? Let me share the `__init__` constructor's code where I getting the subjects, here it is: `self.fields['subject'].queryset = Detail.objects.filter(user=user)` can you tell me what should I change in it to get just subject name using `split('-')[1]`?

Comment: I am unable to post the whole `__init__` constructor code here.

Comment: I will just add the whole PerformanceCalculatorForm Code in my question, let me update it.

Comment: I edited the code block and added the updated code in the form of docstring, have a look at it please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213953/discussion-between-khubaib-khawar-and-paaksing).

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar I updated my answer as well, check out